# Count distinct in a date range, running grass_date

Tags: sql, presto

I'm having a table like this:

| date | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | a |
| 1/2 | b |
| 1/3 | c |
| 1/2 | a |
| 1/3 | d |

and needs to count distinct name available within 7 days from the date in each row.
the result should be:

| date | count | explain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1 | 1 | a |
| 1/2 | 2 | a,b |
| 1/3 | 4 | a,b,c,d |

I've tried these count+if, count+case when, lag functions:

- COUNT(DISTINCT(IF(date_1 between date - INTERVAL '7' DAY and date, name)))
- lag(count(distinct name), 7) over (order by date)

Nothing works, the results are names counted in each day only.

Please advise, great thanks!

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: added presto, great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . Does this do what you want?

```
select min_date, 
       sum(count(*)) over (order by date) as cnt,
       array_agg(array_agg(name)) over (order by date) as names
from (select name, min(date) as min_date
      from t
      group by name
     ) t
group by min_date;
```

EDIT:

Assuming you have one row per date, add a window frame specification:

```
select min_date, 
       sum(count(*)) over (order by date rows between 6 preceding and current row) as cnt,
       array_agg(array_agg(name)) over (order by date rows between 6 preceding and current row) as names
from (select name, min(date) as min_date
      from t
      group by name
     ) t
group by min_date
```

Comment: good one, but I still need 1 more condition which is count only names in 7 days prior to the date in record line

Comment: greetings Gordon. Using min(date) will result in names counted in first day record only, while I still need to count distinct in every date that name appeared.
tried remove min() but Presto calculated too long for my 50M+ lines DB. I may try to switch to python to calculate this.
great thanks!

Comment: oh another try and got what I need based on your help.
saved my day. kudos Gordon!

`select date, cardinality(names) 
from 
(select txn_date, 
array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(array_agg(distinct name)) over (order by date rows between 29 preceding and current row))) as names
from (select distinct date, name from t)
group by 1)`